# Moq callback method not hit within lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, callback, moq

I have an issue while trying to get parameter values from MOQ Method using `Callback`.

```
// Test 1 - can get parameters in moq method callback - OK
var test = _myService.GetValues(9, 9).ToList();

// Test 2 - can not drill into moq method callback - KO
var test2 = mylist
.Select(x => _myService.GetValues(x.p1, x.p2).ToList());

// with:
var l1 = new list<int>();
var _myService = new Mock<MyService>();

_myService
    .Setup(x => x.GetValues(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>()))
    .Returns(something)
    .Callback<int, int>((a, b) => l1.Add(a));
```

Can someone explain me why ?

Comment: what errors are u getting? what are something and mylist?

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem other wise the question will remain unclear and will be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the `Select` query is enumerated the lambda expression is not executed. That is why it appears not to work.

Enumerate the select and everything should work as expected.

```
var test2 = mylist
.Select(x => _myService.GetValues(x.p1, x.p2).ToList())
.ToList();
```

OR

```
var test2 = mylist
.Select(x => _myService.GetValues(x.p1, x.p2).ToList());
foreach(var x in test2) { ... }
```